# COMPILATION ISSUES : FFMPEG CODE ON VS2012

Tags: ffmpeg

I have downloaded FFMPEG source code(***c code***) by the following link

http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

After that,I have completed the configuration part then i was generated and linked the library files ***[avcodec-54.lib,avdevice-54.lib,avfilter-3.lib,avformat-54.lib,avutil-52.lib,swresample-0.lib,swscale-2.lib ]***on Microsoft Visual Studio C++ by creating a new project by including all .c and header files.

***Referred Links:***
http://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows

When I was compiling on Visual studio 2010... I am getting more than 300 errors under all the files ***libavcodec,libavdevice,libavfilter,libavformat,libavresample,libavutil,libpostproc,libswresample,libswscale*** like

***ASM ERRORS:***

```
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'data type'
error C2065: '__asm__' : undeclared identifier
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'volatile'
```

***SYNTAX ERRORS:***

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before '.'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
error C2059: syntax error : '.'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2059: syntax error : '}'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2059: syntax error : ','
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Please anyone let me know how to compile a ffmpeg c code on vs2010 successfully.

Comment: "creating a new project by including all .c and header files" That won't do. Did you actually follow the steps described in your referred link ?

Comment: yes. I created a new project and included all ffmpeg .c and header files then i have given libraries .lib files and other setting like additional dependencies(include files) under project properties(c/c++ , linker..)

Comment: What you describe is not part of the steps in your link :)

Comment: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1309...i have followed this link also...what i did was they mention in step 8